# "bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off” when booting Linux based Lupu (Lucid puppy 528.005)

Tags: linux, boot, usb

So, as the name suggests, i'm tring to boot Lupu (Lucid puppy 528.005) installation from a vhd inside a USB on a virtual machine.

When i use only the VHD works like a charm, but when i try to run it from USB, i get this error.

My USB is based (i think i can call it like this) on ventoy-1.0.73 and to boot i use grubfm_multiarch.iso

Is so frustrating that when i use only the VHD works fine, but when i try from USB fails ...

The ultimate goal of this project was to be able to have more than one OS on a single USB that can be fierd up in a real live situation like boot it up from a pc or a laptop.

Comment: Interesting enough, is the fact that using the original ISO is loading nice, but not the VHD version ... hmmm ... i need to investigate further ,,,

Comment: grubfm_multiarch.iso is the culprit, i would guess. I tried to boot up from ISO and the same "ttyty job" message appears ... hmmm ... this needs more investigation.

Comment: If it helps with debugging, in the error message, other than "ttyty job not found", i also have this: lupu_528.sfs not found. Dropping out to initial-ramdisk console...